# Cyclic $G/Z(G)$ implies that $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group where $|G| = pq$ for prime $p$ and $q$. Suppose further that $|Z(G)| = q$. Thus, $Z(G) \cong Z_q$ (it is a cyclic group). Moreover, we see that

$$
|G/Z(G)| = \frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|} = \frac{pq}{q} = p.
$$

Thus $G/Z(G)$ is also a cyclic group.

Why does this imply that $G$ is an abelian group? Our professor stated this today in lecture, and I can't seem to find a concrete reason why.

Comment: If $|G|$ is prime, then one can use Lagrange's theorem to show that $G$ has no non-trivial subgroups. Thus every element other than $e$ generates $G$, in other words $G$ is cyclic. This might be easier than your current method.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G/Z=\langle u Z\rangle$. Let $a,b\in G$, $\exists i,j$ such that $aZ=u^iZ$ and $bZ=u^jZ$. There exists $z_1,z_2 \in Z(G)$ such that $a=u^iz_1$ and $b=u^jz_2$. Clearly, $ab=ba=u^{i+j}z_1z_2$.

Comment: Can we generalize this to say that if a group $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup, then it is abelian?

Comment: @Ryan. I do not think so. Take any element $a\in G$, then $\langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.